# Dynamic content not showing for Google's data tool

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having an issue with my Javascript/Jquery generated content not showing up on Google's "view-source" when typing Ctrl-U on Google Chrome. I'm wanting to apply for Google's AdSense program, but I have gotten denied in the past due to "lack of content", for which I *think* to be caused by Google not being able to see the generated content.

For example, I have a table body, with `id="premiumcontainer"`. I use an Ajax call to grab data from my PHP code, and use Jquery to append that data into that table. While the content inside the table is visible on the actual site, it appears empty in the view-source (ex. `<tbody id="premiumcontainer"></tbody>`).

The table also appears empty on [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).

Would this be a problem for applying for AdSense, and if so, how do I get this generated content to appear on view-source/Google's Tool and allow Google to crawl it?